Using higher kotlin version in a library is impacting the Android app which uses older version
I have Android app using kotlin 1.8.10. And I built a library using Kotlin 1.9.20 and added as a dependency to the app. Building the app now fails due to reasons such as
The corresponding parameter in the supertype 'DB' is named 'db'. This may cause problems when calling this function with named arguments.

Not using the same parameter name throws warning since 1.9 and I am also using warningsAsErrors true in the app.
Should the app really care what kotlin version is used for building the library? Is there a way to shield the app from this type of kotlin version mismatch? I tried excluding
debugImplementation("com.example.mylib:xxx") {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin'
}


Why don't you either: 1. upgrade the application's Kotlin version? 2. Use a version of the library that uses a matching Kotlin version of your application?

You have a number of options here, 1) You can set warningsAsError to false in you app's gradle. 2) You can update your project to new kotlin version. 3) Supress Warning but with caution.

Migrating the app's kotlin version is a bigger effort, will happen but not right away. Can't suppress the warning either.
